# Amount of numbers that are coprime to a Mersenne number

Tags: prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

Let $M_p = 2^p-1$ be a Mersenne number, where $p$ is prime. Is it known that almost every number in the interval $[1, M_p]$ is coprime to $M_p$? That is, is it known that
$$
\lim_{p \to \infty} \dfrac{\phi(M_p)}{M_p} = 1?
$$
Here $\phi$ is the Euler's totient function. If so, do you know a reference? Thanks.

Comment: @EdwardJiang $p$ is prime, but $M_p$ isn't necessarily so - OP says Mersenne _number_, not Mersenne _prime_ (though there are certainly a couple of different common notations here).

Comment: The result is obvious if $M_p$ is prime, and so I meant the cases when $M_p$ is not....

Comment: This may be possible to prove relatively straightforwardly - the smallest possible divisor of $M_p$ is $2p+1$ by the usual theorems, and there can be at most $O(\frac{p}{\lg p})$ distinct divisors (and it's possible that number is _much_ smaller - that's just the trivial bound given the divisor size), so you may be able to use inclusion-exclusion to show that only something like $O(\frac{M_p}{\lg p})$ numbers in the interval can possibly share a factor.

Comment: Thanks Steven. I proved this already by similar, although less precise arguments: I showed that the number of prime divisors of $M_p$ is asymptotically smaller than $p$ itself; this together with the fact that the prime factors are larger than $p$ gives the result. However I was wondering if there's a reference for this elsewhere? Thanks!

Comment: I don't know of any specific references, although given the relative briefness and ease of the argument I have to presume that it's a well-known 'folklore theorem'.

Comment: lol :) ok, thanks

Comment: Do you think this result should be included in the wiki page for Mersenne primes in the section "Theorems about Mersenne numbers"? I find it surprising that the result is not easily found on the web

Answer (score 2):

I originally intended to obtain a reference for this seemingly interesting result, but it seems it is not to be easily found on the web. Therefore I've decided to write the short proof for the convenience of other readers.

Let $\omega(k)$ denote the number of prime divisors of an integer $k$. Now by Euler's product formula for $\phi$ and since each prime factor of $M_p$ is greater than $p$, we have
$$
\dfrac{\phi(M_p)}{M_p} = \prod_{\ell \mid M_p} \left( 1 - \dfrac{1}{\ell}  \right) > \left(  1 - \dfrac{1}{p} \right)^{\omega(M_p)} \to 1
$$
as $p \to \infty$, since 
$$
\lim_{p \to \infty}\dfrac{\omega(M_p)}{p} = 0.
$$
The last can be easily shown to be true from the fact that $\omega(n)$ is bounded on prime powers, while $\log_2(n)$ is not. Finally since $\phi(M_p)/M_p < 1$, the Squeeze Theorem implies the result.

Comment: Looks good to me.